# toast after removing last item from recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a recyclerview with an adapter. I am using the following method in onbindviewholder to remove the items from the list.

```
List<MyList> myList;
Adpater myAdapter = myList.get(position);
myList.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I want a toast after the last item is removed from the list. Please help.

Comment: Just check length of list in adapter if 0 then show toast

Comment: How to set the condition for that ? Have any reference?

Comment: you can set toast after `myList.remove(position);` line.

Comment: your can do`if ( myList.size() == 0 ) showToast(); else myList.remove(position);`

Comment: @Akash That worked

Comment: Yes post that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `toast` after `myList.remove(position);` line.

Answer (score 1):

I see that it is custom adapter, so You can have overrided method to check empty:

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {

    return items.size()==0; //items is example collection

}
```

Use that method

```
if (myAdapter.isEmpty()){
  //here toast show
}
```

Comment: This works generally when list size is 0. How do i check the list size after i remove the item??

Comment: Got it. Thank u :)